# HHVM timing out due to large queue

Tags: nginx, hhvm

I have HHVM setup using TCP upstreams and nginx. Currently there is one app doing two Guzzle Curl requests to two other apps on the same server.

Eventually HHVM just starts to queue all of the requests and then stops responding. It does not give any errors, and its status is still running. The admin side is also still running.

It is not consistent when it will decide to start queuing all of the requests.

Answer (score 0):

This sound like a bug. Please [file it on our GitHub issue tracker](https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/issues), it's much easier to track bugs there than on Stack Overflow. (A gdb backtrace from all threads, to see what they're doing when everything is stuck, would be a good place to start if you know how to get that.)

Comment: Indeed I do. I will see if I can replicate the issue with the debug package. I will make this the accepted answer once I can confirm the issue persists.